# AMD GPU PRO detecting wrong GPU + Gnome visual glitches

Tags: amd-graphics, ubuntu-gnome, gpu, gpu-driver

I've never had any issues with the latest mesa through ppa but still i cannot get the performance boost of amd gpu pro. Amd gpu pro now support my card which is an AMD R7 240.

After install i got stuck on login, but after reinstalling gdm and removing some other bits got it to work, but the proprietary identifies my card as an HD 8500 series card instead of an R7, not to mention gnome desktop is full of visual glitches (wallpaper is sliced with black squares and lines, same with icons on the menu). Is there a way to identify the correct gpu anyhow?

Comment: AMD GPU pro is experimental. I think the stock driver should be enough.

Comment: How is it enough running CSGO with 20fps on lowest settings with mesa 13? when i can run at good on windows and almost normal with amd gpu pro?

Comment: Can you try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <amd-gpu-pro-package-name>`? Or purge, reboot, reinstall both AMD and mesa.

Comment: ive purged the package and even xserver-xorg, re installed it again to no end. I just want to know if this is something on AMD's side or something that i can fix manually. I've already submit this situation to the amd support page. The glitches are there and the GPU is still named as hd 8500 instead of R7